# bitmap.Compress and png or jpg or gif files

Tags: image, xamarin.android

I have image files in the gallery (png, jpg and gif).

I got them from the gallery and I want to save them under the same name with “_+ ” in the gallery.

Is the following code correct?

For example, “s1.jpg” becomes “_+ s1.jpg”

```
        Iv2.SetImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        var strEnd = tv1.Text.Substring(tv1.Text.Length - 4, 4);
        var filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(sdCardPath, "_+ " + tv1.Text);
        var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
        if (strEnd == ".png")
        {
            bitmap2.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, stream);
        }
        else if (strEnd == ".jpg" || strEnd == "jpeg")
        {
            bitmap2.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
        }
        else
        {
            bitmap2.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
        }
        Iv2.SetImageBitmap(bitmap2);
        Tv2.Text = "T+ " + tv1.Text;
        stream.Close();
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to rename the file name ?

Comment: For example, I have this image (s1.png) and I have done something on it. Now I want to save this image in the gallery with the same name and “_+” (_+s1.png) .

Comment: You could try to use  `MediaStore.Images.Media.InsertImage`.